# How to test difference in skewness and kurtosis for two samples with different mean?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

There are several questions asking for comparing these moments for two distributions coming from the same population distribution (i.e. expecting to have the same mean). Examples are [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/241218/how-to-test-for-the-difference-in-skewness-of-two-samples) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173616/are-two-samples-with-skewness-equal?rq=1).

Now, consider a different type of dataset. For example, GDP per capita in 1980 and in 2010, in comparable units, for all countries in the world (this is actually the population and not a sample, but please disregard this issue). We know and actually expect that the mean of these two samples is different; GDP per capita grows over time. So, it makes little sense to directly compare them with e.g. a KS test.

The interesting question is, however: has the **shape** of the GDP per capita distribution change over time? Hence my interest in other moments of the distribution, like skewness and kurtosis. Is there a way to test for this difference taking into account the different means? In other words, **can we compare the shape of two distributions in a way that is independent on their mean?** This is, is there a scale invariant test for comparing distributions?

In case of a negative answer, one alternative I can think of is to normalize the two samples and then run a KS test. However, this requires (afaik) the distributions to be normal, which need not to be the case (and, for the sake of generality, let's assume they are not normal). Is there another way to do achieve this?

Comment: Would you have a way to compare them if they had the same mean? Because you can just add a constant to one of them, balacing the means without changing "anything else", and then perform your skewness-comparison test

Comment: KS test doesn't get you what you want. It will say that the distributions are different, but it won't say why. What's your objection to normalizing or at least subtracting out the mean? (Also, perhaps consider a more robust location estimator, such as median.)

Comment: @David I think KS is one way to compare them if they would have the same mean. They can surely be rescaled, but I'm not sure how exactly. As said, normalising seems to require normality. Translating it is one alternative, but not sure how robust it is. Another option is to divide by the relative means. The question is, which is better? I don't know.

Comment: If by KS, you mean the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (Please avoid the use of potentially misleading abbreviations), you can have distributions with same mean, variance and skewness and still get a positive, so I wouldn't really trust it that much